# Is substring Matching css attr selector considered as a bad practise?

Tags: html, css, substring, string-matching

In order to avoid adding an extra `is-icon` class to each of my icon elements, such as this:

```
<style>
    .is-icon { // Base styling of icon }
    .icon-car { // specific car styling }
</style>
<span class="is-icon icon-car">car</span>
```

I am using this CSS to solve it:

```
<style>
    span[class^="icon-"] { // base icon styling }
    .icon-car { // specific car styling }
</style>
<span class="icon-car">car</span>
<span class="icon-cat">cat</span> ETC...
```

My question is: does `span[class^="icon-"]` css selector is expensive? and which one is a better practise? My understanding is Substring Matching css attr selector is not a bad practise at all, it's just more of a preference. Please help me understand this.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: This is used in various CSS and icon frameworks, so I would say the answer is, it's fine.

Comment: @Paulie_D Missed your coffee this morning? The "specific answerable programming issue" is whether this selector is overly expensive and whether there are better alternatives.

Comment: It's still **opinion-based** as all "best practice" questions are, "Best/Better" are **subjective**...so this is off-topic,

Comment: I was hoping that choosing between substring attr `[class^="bla-"]` and specific `class` is just a matter of preference, hence I was asking in hopes that some CSS nerds could share me their opinions. CSS is not really subjective. For example BEM is preferred because CSS reads from right to left, the more indentation you make, the slower it gets. as in `.featured__title__link` is faster than `.featured { .title { .link {}}}

Comment: @torazaburo Thanks a lot! I guess in this case `class` and `substring attr` are both OK. I will test it when I have the chance and provide the answer here.